# Apostrophe after apostrophe

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

The artifical inteligence generated this sentence and I got in a double.

Does it make sense to put apostrophes like this: Business Contact’s company's workforce.

It means the workforce of the company of the business contact.

I think if I wrote like this, it would be understandable: Business Contact company's workforce.

However, my questions is not whether it is common or not, it is whether it is grammatically correct.

Thanks so much.

Comment: It is grammatically correct - I pulled my mother's friend's cat's tail - but too many may make a sentence seem awkward and clumsy.

Comment: And this one qualifies as quite clumsy. You won't impress by writing like that.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible. An easy example would be, "My father's dog's bone". The bone belongs to the dog and the dog belongs to my father. It is perfectly legitimate to have two possessives in a row like that.

I don't understand the example. Does "business contact" "own" the company in any sense? What does "business contact" refer to here? But maybe it would make sense if I saw the complete context.